# why this c++ code that use libcurl throw error in runtime but when i use valgrind it does not throw any error

Tags: c++, g++, libcurl

when i compile this code with g++ it doesn't throw any error, but in runtime it throw error like
double free or corruption (fasttop)
or tcache_thread_shutdown(): unaligned tcache chunk detected

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <fstream>
#include "arguments.cpp"
using namespace std;


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    const int THREAD_BATCH_SIZE = 100; // set the batch size
    string userurl;
    string wordlistfile;
    arguments(argc, argv, &userurl, &wordlistfile);
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    int count = 0;
    ifstream wordlistcount(wordlistfile);
    string comurl = "";
    string word;
    while(getline(wordlistcount, word)) {
        count++;
    }
    ifstream wordlist(wordlistfile);
    for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
        if ((i - 1) % THREAD_BATCH_SIZE == 0) {
            threads.emplace_back([&] { // creates and starts a thread
                CURL* curl = curl_easy_init(); // initialize a new CURL object for each thread
                curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1L);
                CURLcode res;
                long http_code;
                char *url = NULL;

                for (int j = 1; j <= THREAD_BATCH_SIZE; j++) {
                    getline(wordlist, word);
                    comurl = userurl + word;
                    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, comurl.c_str());
                    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "HEAD");
                    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
                    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
                    curl_easy_getinfo(curl, CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE, &http_code);
                    curl_easy_getinfo(curl, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL, &url); //CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL

                    string color;

                    if (http_code < 200) {color = "\033[1;34m"; /* yellow */}
                    else if (http_code < 300) {color = "\033[1;32m"; /* green */}
                    else if (http_code < 400) {color = "\033[1;33m"; /* blue */}
                    else if (http_code < 500) {color = "\033[1;35m"; /* purple */}
                    else if (http_code < 600) {color = "\033[1;31m"; /* red */}
                    if (http_code != 0 && http_code != 404 && url != NULL) {
                        cout << color << http_code << "   \033[0;97m /" << url << endl;
                    }
                }
                curl_easy_cleanup(curl); // cleanup the CURL object after processing the thread batch
            });
        }
    }
    for (auto& t : threads) { // wait for all threads to finish
        t.join();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

i expected that this program will send many request to a server to check if the page existe (directory bruteforce for an ethical purpose)

Answer (score 2):

```
getline(wordlist, word);
```

It looks like this line gets executed by multiple execution threads. Multiple execution threads appear to be trying to read from the same input stream, into `word`.

None of the classes in the C++ library are thread-safe, including `word`, a single object that's being scribbled over by multiple execution threads.

This is undefined behavior.

```
comurl = userurl + word;
```

`comurl` is also a single object, instantiated in main, that multiple execution threads attempt to modify here, stomping all over each other, and creating more undefined behavior.

There may be more instances of undefined behavior in the shown code, I stopped the analysis at this point.